# How to stop a not_stoppable kernel driver service

Tags: windows, drivers, services

I am having trouble removing a service from my computer.
Running `net stop` says the requested pause continue or stop handle is not valid.
`sc query` says that is is of type KERNEL_DRIVER and NOT_STOPPABLE, how do i stop this service, preferably without restarting?

Comment: What is the name of the Service? Did it install as part of a driver or software, if so what?

Comment: Its bckd and `sc query` says its a kernel driver

Comment: We need more information on the driver, bckd tells us nothing, and you did not answer all my questions.